# Dictation with browser : have Mac Book Pro speak out web pages

Tags: macos, safari, voice-dictation

Can I use dictation to have Firefox/ Safari to read me pages?

Using a MacBook Pro - OS X 10.9.4

Comment: @bmike - your edit broke the question (grammar and logic-wise)

Comment: @KevinGrabhern please edit to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Safari:

Mark text, secondary click (aka right-click), speech.

Alternatively it's also in the edit menu.

Settings can be adjusted in System Preferences -> Speech

Comment: I'll second this. Start with Apple's applications to get speech and dictation set up. Alternative browsers have spotty support for Apple text shortcuts, key shortcuts and accessibility tools since they choose to work cross platform instead of relying on Apple's SDK for app development. Chrome and Firefox are notoriously resistant to adopt Apple's SDK and that's good when you want things different - not so much if you expect stock behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Another way though Safari is good most cases (copy paste URL if its not your preferred browser and you just want a few pages read aloud):

As did copying to Text Edit, after removing formatting  (In text edit can use Menu Format / Make Plain text or paste to text wrangler and then copy afresh and paste to Text edit.)

Comment: Use commenting for this, not answering in the future. Also: in Text Edit you can select plain text in one of the menus to remove formatting (I can't recall which, I'm on my phone)